# why SQL database doesn't connect?

Tags: mysql, database, livecode

i created a database on SQL and i've put it on my livecode stack, and it seems ok, bu the system tells me quote:"Unable to connect to the database:
Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client" i don't understand what is the problem and how to fix it.
I didn't see any costs for creatin an SQL database so i don't understand what means "upgrading to mySQL client"
any ideas?
thanks!

Comment: "upgrading" in the sense of newer version. But you are given to little detail for anyone to help you

Comment: @derpirscher upgrading the client is not possible, since the client is a LiveCode script. The script needs to be changed. 
Samuele you need to ask a new question and give details about the script you're using. Don't copy-paste the error but "describe"  the error to avoid deletion for question being a duplicate.